# std::sort algorithms memory usage

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, memory

I'm wondering whether the standard libraries sorting algorithms (e.g. std::sort) are using the heap memory for sorting.

Is there any reliable source how to find out what kind (heap, stack) and how much of temporary memory is used by a sorting algorithm or any standard library algorithm in general?

The background is that I consider to introduce some of the standard library algorithms into an embedded environment in which a controlled memory usage is crucial. (especially the heap shall not be used).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know if there are any general answers or "guarantees" to this. But if the issue is crucial, then a general answer is probably not good enough anyway. You need an answer for the specific implementation for std::sort and such on the platform you're using. You may be in luck though, since a lot of std stuff (particularly anything templates) is implemented entirely in the C++ headers. In that case there's not really anything stopping you from looking at the implementation yourself to verify everything you're concerned about.

Comment: Just took a browse through a recent standard draft. I see nothing stating that `sort` can't use heap, just requirements on how `swap` is supported. Digging through `swap`, again no details on whether the heap is used to store temporaries during the swap.

Comment: @user4581301 The standard does not even has the concept of "heap" and "stack" to begin with, so any guarantee concerning "where" the memory is allocated would be rather surprising.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The standard has concepts of dynamically allocated memory and local variables, which correspond to heap and stack respectively in implementations.

Comment: @interjay That's {static, automatic, dynamic} storage duration, not "what kind of memory".

Comment: @BaummitAugen And in practice any reasonable implementation will use heap and stack for those storage durations.

Comment: @interjay Until you have some platform without a heap, that somehow manages to implement dynamic storage duration on the "stack" (or some other concept of memory to begin with). The C++ standard is more general than "everyone does it like this so far".

Comment: @BaummitAugen The question asked here is a practical question about a real platform, it isn't a language-lawyer question about unpractical possibilities. Saying that there is an imaginary platform that behaves differently doesn't help. It seems that you're arguing for the sake of arguing.

Comment: @interjay I don't feel like I'm arguing; of course common platforms us the stack and the heap as we know it. However, as my answer states: The important part is that the implementation does the right thing, as in observable effects. What memory it uses for that is irrelevant and rightfully not mandated by the standard. Again: As long as the outcome is right, the "how" does not matter.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well, what memory is used is certainly important in this case (where heap memory is constrained), so I don't understand your point. The outcome won't be "right" if you run out of memory. Again, you seem to be looking at this from a pure standard view, while this question is about what practically happens in a reasonable implementation. Imagine that the question had asked "Will std::sort allocate memory with a dynamic storage duration" if you prefer.

Comment: @interjay One could of course ask *"How does implementation X implement `std::sort` on platform Y?"* and answer "uses heap" or not. But as it stands, I think my answer hits the point: In general, we can't know, some implementations may provide additional guarantees, but it must do as told by the standard.

Comment: True enough to all that. The implementation could use memory from Pluto over quantum entanglement and be correct. I chose my wording poorly when I used heap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What memory the standard library algorithms can use is not mandated by the standard, so the implementation can generally do as it wants. That includes allocating heap memory.

You can check if some *specific* implementation provides the guarantees you want, but again, in general, you have no control over how the implementation implements its algorithms.

---

However:

> The background is that I consider to introduce some of the standard library algorithms into an embedded environment in which a controlled memory usage is crucial. (especially the heap shall not be used).

The implementation *must* make sure that its algorithms do what they are supposed to do as defined by the standards. That means: If you have a C++ compiler that supports your target environment, it must do the right thing on said target platform, however it achieves that.

In particular: If your platform does not have a heap, any implementation that supports it must not use the heap.

Comment: `std::sort` *may not* in practice use the heap, because it *may not* throw `bad_alloc` as far as I know? (unless your code does)  (And yes, pathologically it could, with a pointless heap allocation then a catch that ignores the error)

Comment: In the case of std::sort, typically the source code in < algorithm > could be viewed using an editor to see exactly what it's doing. In the case of Visual Studio, std::sort uses a combination of quick sort, heap sort (used to prevent O(n^2) worst case time complexity of quick sort), and insertion sort, all of them being in place sorts, so no apparent allocation of memory from the heap. std::stable_sort() is a variation of merge sort and does allocate a temp buffer (1/2 the size of the original array). The VS implementation of quick sort limits stack space complexity to O(log2(n)).

Comment: @Yakk The standard library implementation could use some non-throwing allocation I suppose, and getting terminated by the OS is not  an exception in the standard sense. However, I believe this falls under the second part of my answer: `std::sort` must sort and not throw, *how* it does this need not concern us users.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) says `std::sort` can throw `bad_alloc`

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is under the `ExecutionPolicy` cases, which are permitted to allocate resources (for example, a message being sent to a worker thread, or whatever).