# C++ algorithms heap allocation guarantees

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-lawyer

Are there any guarantees in the C++ standard about non-execution-policy overloads of standard algorithms not making free store (i.e. heap) allocations?

I'm doing real time processing, and would like to use, e.g., `std::max_element`, but I don't see any guarantee about it not allocating on the heap. It makes sense that it doesn't, but I don't see that specified anywhere. Perhaps I am missing some general clause which does guarantee that?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475062/748188

Comment: There's not even a guarantee that `operator+(int,int)` doesn't use the heap. Why do you expect such a guarantee for more complex algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard does prohibit any algorithm from allocating memory. Since knowledge whether an algorithm allocates memory may be useful/necessary omission of this specification may be seen as a defect (I don't think there is an outstanding defect on this topic). Specifying which algorithms are not allowed to allocate memory shouldn't be too bad as long as it is clear that these allocations only cover the algorithm's own operations rather than operations on its parameters: the algorithms *may* use copies of objects which in turn may require memory allocations.

In theory it is conceivable that some algorithms may benefit from a temporary buffer and could allocate memory. However, in practice there a few algorithms which will do so (e.g., `rotate()` can benefit from allocating memory). Algorithms like `std::max_element()` won't allocate memory although it isn't specified not to.

Comment: For some algorithms (`std::inplace_merge`, for example), the complexity requirements explicitly change if temporary storage (i.e., heap storage) is available. Providing that temporary storage is the primary role of `std::get_temporary_buffer`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: agreed. However, `std::max_element()` is rather unlikely to require additional memory. It would be good if the specification were tightened to explicitly prohibit the use of additional memory but as that is not done the best which can be done for now is to make reasonable assumptions (or not to use the algorithms).

Comment: "The standard does prohibit any algorithm from allocating memory" - I've spent too long now looking for this and the only text I can find to this effect is 25.2.6 which seems like it is about something else. Do you have a specific cite?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a mention of such guarantee directly. However, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) mentions no exception for `std::max_element` for the non-execution policy overloads.

Note that it does mention a `std::bad_alloc` for the execution policy overloads.

If this information is correct, then this would imply that the non-execution policy overloads cannot allocate memory on the heap (otherwise they could throw a `bad::alloc`).

Comment: It can still `try catch` and then fall back to implementation without allocation ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 uh right, missed that. However, that would be a nasty way of doing it and I hope no implementation does it

Comment: Does that the fact that nothing is said with regards to exceptions about the standard non-execution policy algorithms *formally* mean that they are not allowed to throw exceptions?

Comment: @Danra anyhow the only 100% trustworthy reference is the standard, cppreference is quite reliable, but if you need a 100% guarantee....also note Jarods comment. My reasoning has a serious flaw, because even if the method does not throw there might be exception internally. I only left the answer because there was no other, maybe I will delete it.